# vForm errors not being able to display in the form for the user

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

this is my form

```
 <form @submit.prevent="updatePassword">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Old Password</label>
                            <input v-model="form.old_password" type="password" name="old_password"
                                   class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': 
form.errors.has('old_password') }">
                            <has-error :form="form" field="old_password"></has-error>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>New Password</label>
                            <input v-model="form.password" type="password" name="password"
                                   class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': 
form.errors.has('password') }">
                            <has-error :form="form" field="password"></has-error>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Confirm Password</label>
                            <input v-model="form.password_confirmation" type="password" 
name="password_confirmation"
                                   class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': 
form.errors.has('password_confirmation') }">
                            <has-error :form="form" field="password_confirmation"></has-error>
                        </div>

   <button :disabled="form.busy" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
                    </form>
```

this is my script

```
<script>

export default {
    name: "Password",
    data(){
        return{
            form: new Form({
                old_password: '',
                password: '',
                password_confirmation: ''
            }),
        }
    },
    methods:{
        updatePassword(){
            axios
                .post(`/data/password/update/${this.$parent.userId}`, this.form)
                .then((response) => {
                    if(response.data === 'success'){
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Update',
                            'Password Updated Successfully',
                            'success'
                        );
                    }
                })
                })
        },
    },
    mounted() {

    }
}
</script>
```

this is in my main js

```
import {
Form,
HasError,
AlertError,
AlertErrors,
AlertSuccess
} from 'vform';

window.Form = Form;
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError);
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError);
Vue.component(AlertErrors.name, AlertErrors);
Vue.component(AlertSuccess.name, AlertSuccess);
```

this in my laravel backend validation

```
public function passwordUpdate(Request $request, $id)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'old_password' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);
}
```

when I submit an empty form I expect that it will show the errors on the page for the user to see but nothing happens instead in get this error in the console

**Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.form.errors.has is not a function"**

What am I not doing right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `updatePassword` method you used axios directly while when you want `vform` handle it for you use `form.post` like this:

```
    methods:{
        updatePassword(){
             this.form.post(`/data/password/update/${this.$parent.userId}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    if(response.data === 'success'){
                        Swal.fire(
                            'Update',
                            'Password Updated Successfully',
                            'success'
                        );
                    }
                })
            })
        },
    },
```